# How to get all lines between first and last occurrences of patterns?

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I trim a file (well input stream) so that I only get the lines ranging from the first occurrence of pattern `foo` to the last occurrence of pattern `bar`?

For instance consider the following input :

```
A line
like
foo
this 
foo
bar
something
something else
foo
bar
and
the
rest
```

I expect this output:

```
foo
this 
foo
bar
something
something else
foo
bar
```

Comment: Single pass stream or a file?  This is much easier to do when random access is allowed.  With a file you would just find the first `foo` and last `bar` and print everything in between, if anything.  With a stream you would have to read until the first `foo`, and buffer all subsequent lines in memory until EOF, flushing the buffer every time a `bar` is seen.  This could mean buffering the entire stream in memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed -n '/foo/{:a;N;/^\n/s/^\n//;/bar/{p;s/.*//;};ba};'
```

The sed pattern matching `/first/,/second/` reads lines one by one. When some line matches to `/first/` it remembers it and looks forward for the first match for the `/second/` pattern. In the same time it applies all activities specified for that pattern. After that process starts again and again up to the end of file.

That's not that we need. We need to look up to the last matching of `/second/` pattern. Therefore we build construction that looks just for the first entry `/foo/`. When found the cycle `a` starts. We add new line to the match buffer with `N` and check if it matches to the pattern `/bar/`. If it does, we just print it and clear the match buffer and janyway jump to the begin of cycle with `ba`.

Also we need to delete newline symbol after buffer clean up with `/^\n/s/^\n//`. I'm sure there is much better solution, unfortunately it didn't come to my mind.

Hope everything is clear.

Comment: It works! It would be super cool if you could walk us through the construction of such a command. I'd feel dumb simply copy/pasting it from some website online ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the explanation with the answer. Now it is in the post.

Comment: In some `sed` versions e.g. BSD sed (which is what's found on Macs), tags need to be followed by a newline or end of string, so the following tweak is necessary:  `sed -n -e '/foo/{:a' -e 'N;/^\n/s/^\n//;/bar/{p;s/.*//;};ba' -e '};'`  This *also* works on GNU sed, so I think this modification (multiple `-e` args ending an arg after each branch name) is a good portable habit to get into when using branches in sed.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it with a little Perl one-liner.

```
cat <<EOF | perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = undef; } print $1 if(/(foo.*bar)/s)'
A line
like
foo
this 
foo
bar
something
something else
foo
bar
and
the
rest
EOF
```

yields

```
foo
this 
foo
bar
something
something else
foo
bar
```

Comment: If this were code-golf, you could use `E` instead of `e` and `-00777` instead of the `$/` bit (see perlrun(1)). Which would shorten it to: `perl -0777 -nE 'say /(foo.*bar)/s'`, still sort of readable.

Comment: I didn't know about these flags! I am sure that especially `-0[octal]` will find it's way in my workflow! Thanks for that

Answer (score 4):

Here's a two-pass GNU sed solution that doesn't require much memory:

```
< infile                                     \
| sed -n '/foo/ { =; :a; z; N; /bar/=; ba }' \
| sed -n '1p; $p'                            \
| tr '\n' ' '                                \
| sed 's/ /,/; s/ /p/'                       \
| sed -n -f - infile
```

#### Explanation

- First `sed` invocation passes infile and finds first occurrence of `foo` and all subsequent occurrences of `bar`.
- These addresses are then shaped into a new `sed` script with two invocations of `sed` and one `tr`. Output of the third `sed` is `[start_address],[end_address]p`, without the brackets.
- Final invocation of `sed` passes the `infile` again, printing the found addresses and everything in between.

Answer (score 2):

If the input file fits comfortably in memory, [keep it simple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47942/how-to-get-all-lines-between-first-and-last-occurrences-of-patterns/47951#47951).

If the input file is huge, you can use [`csplit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/csplit.html) to break it into pieces at the first `foo` and at every subsequent `bar` then assemble the pieces. The pieces are called `piece-000000000`, `piece-000000001`, etc. Choose a prefix (here, `piece-`) that won't clash with other existing files.

```
csplit -f piece- -n 9 - '%foo%' '/bar/' '{*}' <input-file
```

(On non-Linux systems, you'll have to use a large number inside the braces, e.g. `{999999999}`, and pass the `-k` option. That number is the number of `bar` pieces.)

You can assemble all the pieces with `cat piece-*`, but this will give you everything after the first `foo`. So remove that last piece first. Since the file names produced by `csplit` don't contain any special characters, you can work them over without taking any special quoting precaution, e.g. with

```
rm $(echo piece-* | sed 's/.* //')
```

or equivalently

```
rm $(ls piece-* | tail -n 1)
```

Now you can join all the pieces and remove the temporary files:

```
cat piece-* >output
rm piece-*
```

If you want to remove the pieces as they are concatenated to save disk space, do it in a loop:

```
mv piece-000000000 output
for x in piece-?????????; do
  cat "$x" >>output; rm "$x"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way with `sed`:

```
sed '/foo/,$!d;H;/bar/!d;s/.*//;x;s/\n//' infile
```

It appends each line in `/foo/,$` range (lines `!` not in this range are `d`eleted) to `H`old space. Lines not matching `bar` are then deleted. On lines that match, the pattern space is emptied, e`x`changed with the hold space and the leading empty line in the pattern space is removed.

With huge input and few occurrences of `bar` this should be (much) faster than pulling each line into pattern space and then, each time, checking the pattern space for `bar`.
Explained:

```
sed '/foo/,$!d                     # delete line if not in this range
H                                  # append to hold space
/bar/!d                            # if it doesn't match bar, delete 
s/.*//                             # otherwise empty pattern space and
x                                  # exchange hold buffer w. pattern space then
s/\n//                             # remove the leading newline
' infile
```

---

Sure, if this is a file (and fits in memory) you could simply run:

```
 ed -s infile<<'IN'
.t.
/foo/,?bar?p
q
IN
```

because `ed` *can* search forward *and* backward.
You could even read a command output into the text buffer if your shell supports process substitution:

```
printf '%s\n' .t. /foo/,?bar?p q | ed -s <(your command)
```

or if it doesn't, with `gnu ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' .t. /foo/,?bar?p q | ed -s '!your command'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on any UNIX system and without reading the whole file or input stream into memory at one time:

```
$ awk '
    f {
        rec = rec $0 ORS
        if (/bar/) {
            printf "%s", rec
            rec = ""
        }
        next
    }
    /foo/ { f=1; rec=$0 ORS }
' file
foo
this
foo
bar
something
something else
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep could do it also (well, GNU grep):

```
<infile grep -ozP '(?s)foo.*bar' | tr '\0' '\n'

<infile grep -ozP '        #  call grep to print only the matching section (`-o`)
                           #  use NUL for delimiter (`-z`) (read the whole file).
                           #  And using pcre regex.
(?s)foo.*bar               #  Allow the dot (`.`) to also match newlines.
' | tr '\0' '\n'           #  Restore the NULs to newlines.
```

For the input from the question body:

```
$ <infile grep -ozP '(?s)foo.*bar' | tr '\0' '\n'
foo
this 
foo
bar
something
something else
foo
bar
```